# How to solve the modular equations using the extended Euclidean algorithm: $48x \equiv 30 \pmod{81}\,$?

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

Since $\gcd(48,81)>1,$  then $48x \equiv 30 \pmod{81}$  by $3$.

I get   $16x \equiv 10 \pmod{27}.$
Then I do extended Euclidean algorithm and got
$$27=1*16+11$$
$$16=1*11+5$$
$$11=2*5+1$$
$$5=5*1+0,$$
then $x=22$ but what would be the next step?

Answer (score 1):

What you solved was the inverse of the coefficient $16\bmod 27$, which is indeed $22$. Now you have to multiply by the given constant $10$ on the right side of the equation, thus $22×10\equiv\color{blue}{4\bmod 27}$.

Comment: if you multiply by 10 then the left hand side becomes 220x?

Comment: No, you have $16^{-1}\equiv22$ from the algorithm, and then multiply by $10$ to get $16^{-1}×10\equiv220\equiv4$, which matches the equation $16x\equiv10$ you set out to solve.

Comment: Thank you now I understand

Comment: There are more than one solutions $(4,31,58)$.

Comment: $\bmod\color{blue}{27}$.

Comment: @kelalaka How do I find the steps to find 31 and 58?

Comment: @michael you don't, because you reduced the problem to $\bmod 27$. Thus $4\equiv31\equiv58$.